# ORDER BY $variable set AFTER query?

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

I have this code:

```
<?php 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM board") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data )) 
{ 
    Print " ".$info['id']." ";
    myOtherQuery($info['id']);
}

function myOtherQuery($id) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(is_following_board_id) FROM follow WHERE is_following_board_id='$id'");
    $c = mysql_result($result, 0);
}
?>
```

It lists all ID's with a number beside it, defined as `$c` above in the second query.

For simplicity I have remove the HTML of the code but it aligns in a table.

I'm trying to `ORDER BY` `$c`, but don't know how to do it. Since it is defined AFTER the select query: `$data = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM board")`

It errors if I add: `$data = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM board ORDER BY '$c'")`

Is there anything I can add to the bottom of the code to make this order by work?

Comment: $c denotes a score attributed to the id indicating popularity. I'm trying to order by popularity, as in a "top 100" of something.

Comment: Is `$c` a column? Also, your code is highly injectable. Learn how to use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) prepared statements.

Comment: You can only use ORDER BY using a column name not by a variable that contains a content from the table.

Comment: You can use an alias like COUNT(is_following_board_id) as c and then use ORDER BY c ASC (OR Desc).

Comment: Wouldn't I have to define what $c meant beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this in one query, by aggregating the results:

```
select is_following_board_id, sum(is_following_board_id) as cnt
from follow
group by is_following_board_id
order by cnt desc;
```

Your approach was to fetch the result and then fetch the count.  Rather inefficient, because SQL is designed for this type of query.

Comment: For simplicity I only include the select with $c in it. There are three more queries, the code would be really complicated as one statement

Comment: @Seth-77 . . . One query would be the way to get them in sorted order.  Otherwise, you have to read the data into an array and sort it in the application.